# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cPickle' on Python 3.7.3

Tags: python, pickle

import cPickle as pkl
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "preprocess_wiki.py", line 13, in 
    import cPickle as pkl
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cPickle'

Comment: Very broad. Is the module installed to your system?

Comment: `cPickle` is a Python 2.x thing, it doesn't exist in Python 3.x anymore. The corresponding C implementation is now an implementation detail of the `pickle` package which is in the standard library; it will automatically use (the equivalent of) `cPickle`, so there's no need to refer to it explicitly.

Answer (score 9):

> A common pattern in Python 2.x is to have one version of a module
>   implemented in pure Python, with an optional accelerated version
>   implemented as a C extension; for example, pickle and cPickle. This
>   places the burden of importing the accelerated version and falling
>   back on the pure Python version on each user of these modules. In
>   Python 3.0, the accelerated versions are considered implementation
>   details of the pure Python versions. Users should always import the
>   standard version, which attempts to import the accelerated version and
>   falls back to the pure Python version. The pickle / cPickle pair
>   received this treatment.

So Just use `import pickle`
for python 3

[Source](https://askubuntu.com/questions/742782/how-to-install-cpickle-on-python-3-4)